# Remove/Strip extra space from the output of for...loop in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template I need to print some items and add "," after each one, unless it is the last item.

So here is my code:

```
<li>
    <strong>Category</strong>:
    {% spaceless %}
    {% for t in project.technology.all %}
    {{ t.title }}
    {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
</li>
```

While it works, it adds an extra whitespace between each item and ",", so what I see is like this:

`Tech1 , Tech2 , Tech3` while it should be `Tech1, Tech2, Tech3`

Even `spaceless` template tag is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of [**`{% spaceless %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) says:

> **Only space between tags is removed** – not space between tags and text.

It is thus only the space between tags, not between tags and text, text and text, etc.

You can render this with:

```
<li>
    <strong>Category</strong>:
    {% for t in project.technology.all %}
        {{ t.title }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</li>
```

we thus will not render a space between `{{ t.title }}` and the comma, since these are all template tags that do not output anything.